# How do storyboards work in iOS 5?

Tags: storyboard, ios5

I can't seem to figure out how they work. Please help! I can't figure out how to add .xib's to them either.

Comment: This storyboard app is probably the best one we've seen. http://youtu.be/B4ZTrMveSZM?hd=1

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Maybe a tutorial would help you. [This one](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html) seems to be quite simple *and* it has screenshots.

**Edit:** [@Andz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659084/how-do-storyboards-work-in-ios-5/6659173#comment18020955_6659173) recommends [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1), which is a bit more beginner-friendly.

Comment: Thanks! It really would have helped if Apple would link to a programming guide about this on there developer website.

Comment: Or spend the time to write their own ;)

Comment: @Blender They finally did! See my answer below.

Comment: and if you are looking for a reference FAQ on storyboard: http://2cupsoftech.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/faq-on-ios5-storyboard/

Comment: I found Tran's tutorials VERY hard to follow because it skips steps that beginners will not know how to execute. Also, the blog template he uses with its big fixed header section lowers usability considerably. 

This storyboard tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1 is much, much better and I've learned a lot with it.

Comment: @Andz: Thanks, I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Apple provided a nice walkthrough in their "developer tools kickoff" video from WWDC. I found it helpful. If you're a registered developer, you can check it out here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#developer-tools-kickoff

Answer (score 7):

I have just created my own tutorial that outlines some of the new features of Storyboards check it out [here http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219). The WWDC video is a very good tutorial but there are somethings it doesn't cover, such as simple things like how do you set the entry point of your Storyboard,or how to get a handle to a popover that has been created by a Segue popover transition

I have also added a new practical example based on todo list that should help people build a deeper understanding [please check it out.](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=558)

Answer (score 4):

Apple recently released (Jan, 2012) an example app with source code that uses Storyboards titled "Your Second iPhone App."

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Just to share my happy findings a few days ago, here are the new iOS Lectures from Stanford (Fall 2011):
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

The episode on multiple mvc could be just the right one ;) *happy watching*